# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory

Tags: java

What I am doing wrong? Thank you! 
Libs: http://cs621531.vk.me/v621531427/4ebb/vU1vHpBjyhQ.jpg sorry, it's uncutted.
Pom: http pastebin.com/7rSWG89Q
Full stacktace: http://pastebin.com/uwQsnwGn

```
 @Cacheable(value = "servicesByCategoryId", key = "T(java.lang.String).valueOf(#id).concat('-').concat(" +
            "T(java.lang.String).valueOf(#page)).concat('-').concat(T(java.lang.String).valueOf(#perPage))" +
            ".concat('-').concat(#orderBy).concat('-').concat(#order)")
```

```
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xsi:schemaLocation=
               "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vse.uslugi"/>
    <cache:annotation-driven key-generator="enhancedDefaultKeyGenerator"/>
    <bean id="enhancedDefaultKeyGenerator" class="...utilities.generators.EnhancedDefaultKeyGenerator"/>
```

---

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dependency issue.
Try without ehcache depency to see if it works. If not, try version "2.8.3" of ehcache which should be the one Spring 4 wants.

Comment: 2.8.3 - result is the same. :-(

Comment: can you share your pom? can you try 2.6.5?

Comment: 2.6.5 - result is the same too. :-(

Comment: can you remove ehcache dependency and remove <scope>provided</scope> parts? there's a dependency clash between spring and ehcache or hibernate and ehcache

Comment: Thank you! http://codinko.com/2014/01/13/ehcache-spring-maven-example/ was helpful. slf4j was missed.